# Magento - Search only parent products

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento installation with a few products in, these are Configurable products and when browsing the categories only the top level product shows up, then when you go to the product page you get to choose the configurable options.

However, when I search for "Cup", it will return 3 different products, one will be the main configurable product, and the other 2 will be the "simple" products, as there's an option of White or Black for the configurable product.

My question is, how can this be changed to only show the "parent/configurable" product?

I've hunted through the Magento settings under Catalog > Catalog Search, etc, but I cannot find anything to correct this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

go to

1) catalog->manage products

2) select simple(assosciate) product change *Visibility* to **Not Visible Individually** in general tab

hope this help

Comment: Just figured this out a few minutes ago, thanks for answering anyway!